# Angular 2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < when installing module

Tags: javascript, angular

I have tried installing a module for popups on my Angular2 project (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-opd-popup this one specifically) but once I install it and try using it I keep getting the mentioned error.

This is my systemjs.config.js file:

```
 var isPublic = typeof window != "undefined";

(function(global) {

  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   (isPublic)? '@angular' : 'node_modules/@angular',
    'rxjs':                       (isPublic)? 'rxjs' : 'node_modules/rxjs'

  };

  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ng2-opd-popup':              { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade'
  ];

  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

I tried using this module on another project and it worked perfectly but it doesn't work on this one for some reason... I will provide any other piece of code if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the code where you import it into your project? --- edit: on a side note, this used to happen to our project quite regularly when using SystemJS; its why we made the switch to webpack.

Comment: import { Popup } from 'ng2-opd-popup';
I use this to import the module into the project, I also added it into de @NgModule:
PopupModule.forRoot()